# Why Does Max Length Formula Throw #VALUE! Error?

Tags: excel, max, string-length, maxlength

I have 600 rows of data in Excel and I've copied them to a new worksheet and set the cells as text (also tried general format). When I type the formula below, it doesn't give me the MAX length of data in the column:

=MAX(LEN(A1:A600))

Instead, I'm left with the #VALUE! error. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have `#VALUE!` in one of the cells?

Comment: There is not #VALUE! in any of the cells. The data ranges from dates, currency, text and numbers all stored as text.

Comment: Did you Array Enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: No, not sure what you're referring to. I manually typed that formula and just hit enter.

Comment: Manually type the formula and then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Fun fact: the formula returns `#VALUE!` specifically because you placed it on a row that is not 1-600. If you placed it in a row 1-600, it would return the length of the value from that row in the range A1:A600. Because it's outside of that range, height wise, it returns `#VALUE!`. But you should have used ctrl+shift+enter, yes.